# Transforming nested JSON with pyjq

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to transform the JSON from this:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "ver": "3.0"
  },
  "cols": [
    {
      "name": "val"
    }
  ],
  "rows": [
    "cols": [
      {
        "name": "ts"
      },
      {
        "name": "v0"      
      },
      {
        "name": "v1"        
      },
      {
        "name": "v2"
      },
      {
        "name": "v3"        
      },
      {
        "ts": {
          "_kind": "dateTime",
          "val": "2021-07-07T00:10:00-07:00",
          "tz": "Los_Angeles"
        },
        "v3": {
          "_kind": "number",
          "val": 6167699.5,
          "unit": "kWh"
        }
      },
      {
        "ts": {
          "_kind": "dateTime",
          "val": "2021-07-07T00:15:00-07:00",
          "tz": "Los_Angeles"
        },
        "v0": {
          "_kind": "number",
          "val": 808926.0625,
          "unit": "m\\u00b3"
        },
        "v1": {
          "_kind": "number",
          "val": 112999.3046875,
          "unit": "m\\u00b3"
        },
        "v2": {
          "_kind": "number",
          "val": 8823498,
          "unit": "kWh"
        }
      }
      
    ]
  }
```

to a more simplified form using the pyjq module:

```
{
  "data": {
    "v0": [
      [
        "first timestamp",
        val
      ],
      [
        "second timestamp",
        val
      ]
      
    ],
    "v1": [
      [
        "first timestamp",
        val
      ],
      [
        "second timestamp",
        val
      ]
     ] 
    }
  }
```

I got started with the pyjq module, however I'm unsure about how to proceed with place two values (one str, one float) within the [] separated by a comma. Here's my code (returns error as expected).

```
import json
import pyjq
with open('file.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
transformed = pyjq.all('{data: { meter_id_1: [[[.rows[].val.rows[].ts.val + "," + .rows[].val.rows[].v0.val]]}}', data)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is pyjq compatible enough with upstream jq for this to be considered just a jq problem?

Comment: ...it looks like pyjq calls the real jq, so there's no good reason for this to be a pyjq question instead of just a jq question.

Comment: The problem here is that you're inserting __literal__ commas, where you should be inserting a syntactic comma. `[foo, bar]`, not `[foo + "," + bar]`

Comment: However, your input JSON isn't valid syntax, so this can't be tested. (When you're deleting items from your data to make a more minimal [mre], be sure you delete the trailing comma on whatever is now the new last item in any dictionary/object).

Comment: Even with the edits, the JSON syntax is still invalid. `{"name: "ts",}` for example needs to be `{"name": "ts"}` without the extra comma.

Comment: As of revision 3: Still invalid JSON syntax. Please test it yourself before putting it in the question.

Comment: Specifically, `"rows": [ "cols": [` isn't valid because `"cols":` is only valid in an object, not a list.

Comment: (Also, what do you mean with `val` in the sample output? Having that as a bare string isn't valid JSON syntax).